# Parsing attributes using SAX in android

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

Is it possible to parse attributes from an xml file using SAX parser?

ex: I am able to easily parse:

```
<author>Hina2</author>
```

Result: Hina2

How do I parse the attributes from:

```
<text author="Hina2" timeModified="timestampgoeshere" 
pos="pre" priority="0" thumbUrl="text2" url="textfull2"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

startElement method has Attributes as parameter. You can get attributes of element from that parameter. You may refer this link for [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/org.xml.sax/GetAttr.html).

Answer (score 0):

if your using the android sax version then you can go about it like this

```
    text.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener(){
                public void start(Attributes attr)
                {
                    String value = attr.getValue("author");

                    currentMessage.setAuthor(value.toString());
                }
        });
```